# Reading .DXF files

Tags: c#, autocad, dxf

Does anyone know of source code, ideally in C# or similar, for reading .DXF files (as used by AutoCAD etc)? If not code, then tables showing the various codes (elements / blocks / etc) and their meanings?

I am writing a reader myself, and have dead tree documentation detailing the format, but am trying to avoid writing e.g. a converter from each of the 255 ACI colours to RGB... Thanks!

Comment: Also a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169390/open-source-cad-drawing-dwg-library-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cadlib](http://www.woutware.com/cadlib.html) from WoutWare have I been using for a couple of projects with good results.

Comment: We have gone with this - the price was right, and it's a nicely put together (and properly commented!) library.

Comment: Been using this product for over 5 years now.. It's great

Comment: And now with NET-Core, it also works on Linux, and Mac ! Fully managed ! No native binaries required !

Answer (score 7):

I have work a couple of years at developing my own [DXf-Viewer in java](http://www.hauk-sasko.de/fileadmin/dxf_viewer/dxf_viewer_applet.html) (you could drop your own DXF file or an URL on the viewer) for 2D drawings.
 The published information from AutoCAD is a good base but doesn't explain how it works.
 Becoming member of the Open Design Alliance, will give you the possibility to convert several CAD formats to DXF. It may be a good idea if you are developing a commercial product.
There is a german book (http://www.crlf.de/Verlag/DXF-intern/DXF-intern.html) about DXF which really explain this format. It's expensive, but could save days of search.
The colors in the DXF Format are indexed, you must have a converter from ACI to RGB. Be careful with values 0 and 1 which having a special meaning.

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

Update in case someone is still looking...
It's the same library, just including both links.

https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf
https://www.nuget.org/packages/netDXF/

Comment: netDxf is good if you are ok with a net framework 4.5 depedency. If you need netcore/netstandard support, I've had good results with https://github.com/ixmilia/dxf

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately AutoCAD publish the DXF format information here: [DXF Formats](https://web.archive.org/web/20090206091720/http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=12272454&linkID=10809853)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the [Open Design Alliance](http://www.opendesign.com/home).  It's a while since I looked at it myself, but they had a load of C libraries for dealing with various AutoCAD files.

Comment: The prices are, however, seriously steep, especially if you intend to actually write software which also the library and then sell it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dxfreader.aspx) is a link to a CodeProject dxf reader; it seems very limited (and not particularly well done) though.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dxf) is another open source dxf reader, in Java. Buggy however!