# Reading a Dxf file with Java

Tags: java, dxf

I am trying to write/find some code in Java which reads dxf files and stores geometry from the "Entities" section into arrays so that I can later import that information into Oracle 11g in terms of tables.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10):

I've used [kabeja](http://kabeja.sourceforge.net/) recently and haven´t had any problems, though I did quite simple tasks. If you just want to bring those geometries into an array it will do the job (in other cases I can't tell). 
If you already know the DXF format you will have no problems to get started. It can get as easy as follows (e.g. to extract some circle entities):

```
Parser parser = ParserBuilder.createDefaultParser();
parser.parse("path/file.dxf", DXFParser.DEFAULT_ENCODING);
DXFDocument doc = parser.getDocument();
DXFlayer layer = doc.getDXFLayer("layer_name");
List<DXFCircle> arcs = layer.getDXFEntities(DXFConstants.ENTITY_TYPE_CIRCLE);
```

The documentation is a bit incomplete, but it has decent javadocs and clean api.

Comment: Hay can you explain how to change the size of the image which generated using kabeja.

Comment: i'm sorry... i haven't used that functionality. i've only extracted dxf entities and rendered them to a jpanel.

Answer (score 7):

For some feedback of general interest read [Reading .DXF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000785/reading-dxf-files)

There's a number of Java libraries that implement a DXF reader/writer like [kabeja](http://kabeja.sourceforge.net/) (Open Source) and [de-caff](http://caff.de/dxfviewer/) (a free viewer, the libraries it's based on are available commercially).

A word of warning: DXF is way more complicated than it looks at first sight, so if you select a solution test it thoroughly on *your* data.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Kabeja](http://kabeja.sourceforge.net/) in my project and I noticed that it is a very good choice because it is a free and powerful tool.

A autocad line is represented by two extremities (the start and the end point)

Each point has 3 coordinates : `X`, `Y` and `Z`

Below is a 2D method (working on both `X` and `Y`) that takes a dxf file as parameter, parse it and then extracts the lines inside it.

The autocad lines will be readed using kabeja functions, then we can build our own Java `Line`s

```
public class ReadAutocadFile {

    public static ArrayList<Line> getAutocadFile(String filePath) throws ParseException {
        ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Parser parser = ParserBuilder.createDefaultParser();
        parser.parse(filePath, DXFParser.DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        DXFDocument doc = parser.getDocument();
        List<DXFLine> lst = doc.getDXFLayer("layername ... whatever").getDXFEntities(DXFConstants.ENTITY_TYPE_LINE);
        for (int index = 0; index < lst.size(); index++) {
            Bounds bounds = lst.get(index).getBounds();
            Line line = new Line(
                    new Point(new Double(bounds.getMinimumX()).intValue(),
                    new Double(bounds.getMinimumY()).intValue()),
                    new Point(new Double(bounds.getMaximumX()).intValue(),
                    new Double(bounds.getMaximumY()).intValue())
                    );
            lines.add(line);
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Where each `Line` is about two [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)s in Java

```
public class Line {

    private Point p1;
    private Point p2;

    public Line (Point p1, Point p2){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public Point getP1() {
        return p1;
    }

    public void setP1(Point p1) {
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    public Point getP2() {
        return p2;
    }

    public void setP2(Point p2) {
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
public class ReadAutocadFileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("testFile.dxf");
            ArrayList<Line> lines  = ReadAutocadFile.getAutocadFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            for(int index = 0 ; index < lines.size() ; index++){
                System.out.println("Line " + (index +1));
                System.out.print("(" + lines.get(index).getP1().getX() + "," + lines.get(index).getP1().getY()+ ")");
                System.out.print(" to (" + lines.get(index).getP2().getX() + "," + lines.get(index).getP2().getY()+ ")\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

The ArrayList of `Line`s contains all the lines of the autocad file, we can per example draw this arraylist on a `JPanel` so in this way we are migrating completely from autocad to Java.

Comment: @Samane : I don't understand, you mean add a point in the autocad file?

Comment: @Samane : The line is represented by two points (the starting and the ending point), to draw a line in autocad you just have to use the draw line command by pressing the L button and then draw the line.

Comment: No, I mean is that I want to add points to AutoCAD file similar code using `kabeja` library in java.

Comment: @Samane : Kabeja is a Java library for parsing dxf files so we can extract lines and shapes from it only, you cannot draw lines in dxf file using java.

Comment: Oh, Is there another way?