# How to read lines from Blocks in Kabeja?

Tags: java, autocad, dxf

I am using Kabeja to read data from an DXF file. I can read all the Lines and Polylines without any issues. However, I am not able to find the Lines from a Block. I can find the Block along with the Insert entity that places the Block in the drawing. But my goal is to read the Lines that build a Block in the DXF file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300543/reading-dxf-files-with-kabeja-library

Comment: this might help you too :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740736/reading-a-dxf-file-with-java

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Kabeja, but this might help you:

The "insert" entity is a reference to the Block definition inside The Blocks section of the DXF (The BlockTable). So to find the lines inside a block definition You need to read The Definition of that block.

[Link to DXF definiton](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/blocks_in_dxf_files_al_u05_c.htm)