# How to modify a dxf file using java

Tags: java, parsing, dxf

I am newbie to this; I want to edit some dxf file's value using Java.

The problem is that am not sure which viewer to use, there are number of viewers available online but don't have any idea about how to use.

I searched a lot over internet about this but didn't get any proper help. Please help me on this, how to open dxf file and how to edit values from that file; which viewer should I use?

Comment: how to edit dxf file? please help me to edit my dxf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than a viewer you need a parser for the DXF format, i'd check [Kebeja](http://kabeja.sourceforge.net/) as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740736/reading-a-dxf-file-with-java).