# Writing to dxf or dwg format?

Tags: c#, autocad, dxf, dwg

I have the X and Y values for a curve in C# and I want them to be drawn in a dxf or dwg file format using the same C# project.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Only the "copy" command of the values from a Notepad and then "Paste" to Polyline in Acad.

Comment: http://www.opendwg.org/oda-software-libraries/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000785/reading-dxf-files

Comment: Also a partial duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169390/open-source-cad-drawing-dwg-library-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CadLib](http://www.woutware.com/cadlib.html) can write DXF and DWG files, definitely easier than going through the DXF specification yourself. There are a few free libraries out there for writing DXF as well. If you're requirements are basic, then these might be good enough.

Answer (score 5):

A long time ago I wrote a DXF writer with VB.NET 2003, that I have converted to C#. It has methods for line, circle, arc, text, dimension, rectangle, polyline and points. You use it like this:

```
DxfMaker dxf = new DxfMaker();

float[,] points = new float[,]
{
    { 0, 10 },
    { 1, 12 },
    { 2, 17 },
    { 3, 14 },
    { 4, 9  }
};
int N = points.GetLength(0);
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
    dxf.DXF_Line(
        points[i - 1, 0], points[i - 1, 1], 0,
        points[i, 0], points[i, 1], 0);
}

dxf.DXF_Save("curve.dxf");
```

The project with the source code is shared [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11487099/DxfMaker.zip). Caveat is because it was VB originally some of the numerical types are inconsistent (between `float` and `double`) by the results are good. Original code for DXF was taken from elsewhere (see comments) and adapted to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating data in C# the easiest way to the results in AutoCAD is to write a dxf file.  The dxf file is a text file.  Autodesk (maker of AutoCAD) publishes the dxf specification [here](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/acad_dxf0.pdf).  You will need some basic AutoCAD knowledge (blocks/layers/groups etc.) to understand the spec.