# DXF converter in UWP

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp, converters, dxf

I need a DXF converter for my UWP. The library can be paid, it does not matter. Have you used a DXF converter with UWP before?

I want to convert DXF to PDF or Image.

Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily google it.

I found [CadLib 4.0 DWG DXF .NET Library](https://www.woutware.com/cadlib)

Please be sure that it works for UWP as description has all the major .NET project platform but no UWP.

You can read details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000785/reading-dxf-files) SO question.

Comment: Thank you. What I found on Google is not UWP compliant. That's why I wanted to open the topic. Does this channel not get help from people who need to be experienced? Anyway thank you. I will try this. I will write experiences.

Comment: You are welcome @Beyru . But try to elaborate your questions and put all the details of efforts you did like code block or research details. It will develop your skill to solved problem.  Enjoy coding. Cheers :)

Comment: Why downvoted to accepted answer?

Comment: @GaurangDave, not me but the question is clearly off topics  recommending Tools.