# How to extract X,Y coordinations from AutoCad drawing

Tags: c#, autocad

I'm writing a **C#** code to extract data from a **AutoCad drawing**. I managed to display all the data from the drawing in the `RichtextBox` but I only wanted the `X, Y` *coordinations* (*start* and *end points*) of the wires, how should I write the code?

```
// DWGFilePath is the file selected from OpenFileDialog 
var FileStream = new FileStream(
  DWGFilePath, 
  FileMode.Open, 
  FileAccess.Read, 
  FileShare.ReadWrite); 

var file = new StreamReader(FileStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 512);

FinalContent = file.ReadToEnd();

richTextBox1.Text = FinalContent;
```

Comment: What are the data you've read? What is the format of the file, is it dwg (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dwg)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes it is, he write it as variable name and comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169390/open-source-cad-drawing-dwg-library-in-c-sharp
https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/autocad

Comment: @DmitryBychenko 
The data i've retrieved are words and integers, all arranged line by line, part of them is shown below:

VERTEX
  5
2721
330
271E
100
AcDbEntity
  8
L33D0_WIRE
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb2dVertex
 10
**8433.45**
 20
**7463.775**
 70
0
  0
SEQEND

The data i need are the bold ones. i'm thinking if there is a method i can detect the wire from the autocad drawing so i could just retrieve the coordinates.

Comment: @Peace Gusta 
The native format of AutoCad is .dwg and .dxf where .dwg is binary so I suppose can't be read as text. So the code in comment  suggest that You have dxf file. 
in the code for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000785/reading-dxf-files You will find more info and sample how to manage DXF files

Comment: Why you parse a file instead let acad do the job (load the drawing) and ask ACAD via Cä later on to deliver the coordinates ? There is a fine database wher you can ask whatever.